# I have a "Remove" button next to app icon on iTunes' app-page

Tags: itunes

In iTunes, on the app-page, I have somehow got a "Remove" button next to my app icons (left hand window). I can't get rid of the remove button and I'm afraid it deletes my apps permanently.

How did this come about? Does it mean these apps will be taken off iPad only *or* from iTunes altogether, as a permanent delete? How do I correct this, so that all apps are organised on specific pages (on the right hand window) whilst being able to choose which apps transfer to iPad and which stay in iTunes to use or transfer when needed?

Any help for my non-techno brain would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the App section of the iPad that you are viewing on iTunes?

[image]

If so, the Remove button removes just removes the app from the iPad. It only permanently deletes the app from the iPad. You don't have to worry about it being deleted from iTunes or even from your Apple ID. To re-install the app from to your iPad, you will just need to click on "Install" (it will replace the "Remove" button) or go to the App Store, tap Purchases, and find the app, then tap on the icon with the cloud and a down arrow.